# What are the crunchy bits on top of Thai mango with sticky rice?

Tags: dessert, thai-cuisine, sticky-rice

My favorite Thai restaurant makes a fantastic mango and sticky rice dessert, and it seems like it'd be pretty simple to recreate at home. I've searched around the internet for mango and sticky rice recipes, and have found many, but none seem to have the crunchy bits that I find in my local restaurant's version.

Obviously, I can ask at the restaurant next time I'm there, but I'm curious if anybody here knows what these could be?

They are crunchy and about the size of grains of rice, which make me think they might be toasted grains of sticky rice? They could also be some kind of seed or nut...

Does anybody know of any crunchy bits that are traditional on Thai sticky rice with mango?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aha! Found the answer myself!

[This recipe](http://www.realthairecipes.com/recipes/mango-with-sticky-rice/) includes the step "Garnish with toasted sesame seeds or fried salty mung beans." -- I googled "fried salty mung beans" and found the picture below, which is exactly what I was looking for:

[image: fried salty mung beans]

Answer (score 1):

TJ Ellis you're right. It's fried or roasted salty mung beans. 
If you can't find it you can use the other kind of bean to add crispy topping.

Comment: What is the other kind of bean?

Answer (score 0):

I just surveyed many sticky rice with mango recipes.   The only topping that appears at all—crunchy or otherwise—is toasted sesame seeds.   It appears in about 1/3 of the recipes.

Comment: yeah, I've seen that as well, but the bits at the restaurant are bigger than sesame seeds...

Answer (score 0):

The little seeds are smaller than sesame, and they have a little hairlike projection on the end.  They don't taste like sesame but have a mild flavor all their own.